# Dynamically assign single Dojo Tooltip to multiple Nodes

Tags: javascript, dojo, tooltip

Imagine that we have a widget with a list of nodes (e.g. divs). We would like to display a Dojo Tooltip on mouseover. The elements inside are generated dynamically, so we have to add Tooltips programmatically.

The strategy is to first define the `Tooltip` single time during `postCreate` and then pass it to handler-function which will dynamically add it to the nodes.

```
postCreate: function() {
  var _this = this;
  var fooTooltip = new Tooltip();

  this.own(on(this, '.elements-container-item', function(e) {
    lang.hitch(_this, 'onMouseOverHandler')(this, e, fooTooltip);
  });
}
```

What is the proper way to dynamically assign `Tooltip` to mouseover'ed element?

```
onMouseOverHandler: function(node, e, fooTooltip) {
  fooTooltip.set('connectId', [node]); // doesn't work
  fooTooltip.set('label', 'foo label'); // doesn't work as well
}
```

Comment: My thought on this is to use event delegation. i.e Assign the MouseOver event handler on to the list container, which contains the dynamic lists(div's). In the event handler check the `event.target` to see that the list node has been hovered on. If it is the the right node than display the tooltip.

Comment: Thank you, @frank, this idea looks good. I was wondering .set('connectId',  [node]) doesn't work, is it correct way to assign conenctId and label dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this for the tooltip.
Remember you need to require `dojo/query` in  your widget definition.

```
postCreate: function() {
  var _this = this;
  var containerNode = this.domNode; // Assuming that the widget has a domNode

  var fooTooltip = new Tooltip({
     connectId: query('.list-container', containerNode ), // Search the Node starting at the containerNode.
     selector: '.list-container-item',
     getContent: function(matchedNode) {
        console.debug('this is a tooltip for ', matchedNode);
     }
  });

}
```