# Assigning Dojo Tooltip to a NodeList using 'selector' attribute

Tags: javascript, dojo, tooltip

I would like to use example explained in https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tooltip.html#attaching-to-multiple-nodes to assign Tooltip to multiple nodes.

But I would like to pass NodesList instead. Something like this:

```
new Tooltip({
  connectId: query('.list-container'),
  selector: query('.list-container-item'),
  getContent: function(matchedNode) {
    console.debug('this is a tooltip for ', matchedNode);
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, this throws: *TypeError: undefined is not a function*

Comment: Have you required the `dojo/query` module? Try to store a single node in the `connectId` i.e `query('.list-container')[0]`. Also change the selector to a string i.e `selector:'.list-container-item'`

Comment: replacing selector parameter with a string solved it! Thank you, @frank. If you put it as answer, I can approve it as a solution.

Comment: added comment as an answer. Did you get  your previous [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714275/dynamically-assign-single-dojo-tooltip-to-multiple-nodes) answered?

Comment: Yes, can accept as solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require the `dojo/query` module.
Also you need to change the `selector` property to string as shown below.

```
new Tooltip({
  connectId: query('.list-container'),
  selector: '.list-container-item',
  getContent: function(matchedNode) {
    console.debug('this is a tooltip for ', matchedNode);
  }
});
```